# what does "quick walk away" means?

Tags: meaning

I got a sentence like the below on VOA site.
what does "quick walk away" means? Does it means "near" or "close"?

> One of Lou Malnati’s downtown locations is a quick walk away from another Chicago institution

Answer (score 3):

It means the same thing as "a quick walk from":

> One of Lou Malnati’s downtown locations is a **quick walk** from another Chicago institution.

referring to the distance between the "location" and "another Chicago institution". You could walk quickly between them.

*away* can be used to indicate going from one place to another.